# Hosted Kerio Mailserver vs. Hosted Exchange

Tags: exchange, kerio

I'm in the beginning stages of migrating from an internal exchange server (2003) to external hosted services.  We don't have a huge user base, less than 100, but we need to support BlackBerries, iPhones, Outlook RPC/HTTP, etc.

I really like exchange hosted providers (I've used intermedia in the past) but pricing is a bit high.

Does anyone have any experience with Kerio?  It looks great, but I'd like to hear some unbiased opinions.  Or biased if you are really happy working for a particular hosting company ;-)

EDIT

I don't need any special compliance or reporting.  I'm just looking for the basics of hosted email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Kerio hosting from R1sync.com for our company, all of us travel 24/7 and they have never failed us in 2 years. There price seems fair at $5 month paid yearly, and we have a mix of mobile devices Iphone, android and 2 Blackberry's.

Take a look https://www.r1sync.com/

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Microsoft themselves?  Their hosted Exchange is something stupid like $4 a month/user.

Comment: +1, Microsoft's solution comes with 25GB/mailbox vs Rackspace 2GB/Mailbox for $5/month. http://www.microsoft.com/online/exchange-online.mspx Seems to good to be true, I wonder how their support is

Comment: Funny you should mention support.  Heard from a friend that has several hundred mailboxes on MSonline that support is just about nonexistent.

Answer (score 0):

I use Rackspace Hosted Exchange for 2 (very) small clients and its fantastic. One of the clients uses blackberry's and hasn't had any problems, even while traveling in HongKong.

It is $10 per user/month. Not sure if that's best price you are going to find but considering how dependent business is on email the cost is justifiable.